# Can't access Array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am filling an array with objects with `push()` function. Then I'm passing as a parameter to `customTimer` function in the end when I am in the `customTimer` function i trying to access this array cells but i can't.
i tried a few things like `refObjArr[0],refObjArr["0"]` etc.
When I'm trying to `console.log("qweqew",typeof refObjArr)` it returns object and i tried `console.log("Array : ",arr)` i can see objects but i can't access anyway

[image: Objects]

when Im using jQuery makeArray() [function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

```
var arr = $.makeArray(refObjArr)
console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr : ", refObjArr)
console.log("custom Timer -> type arr: ", typeof arr)
console.log("custom Timer -> arr: ", arr)
console.log("is Array " + jQuery.isArray(arr));
```

it gives me true but i still can't acess

**UPDATE :**

```
for (var i = 0; i < detayBodyArray.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: apiAdress + '/api/Gosterge/defParameters?ekrandetayId=' + detayId[i] + '&bodyIdIndex=' + i,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (veri) {
            n = detayId.indexOf(veri[2].ekrandetayId);
            setRefObj[n] = {};

            setRefObj[n].yS = parseInt(veri[2].value);
            setRefObj[n].kS = parseInt(veri[2].value);
            setRefObj[n].ekrandetayId = detayId[veri[2].index]
            setRefObj[n].bodyId = bodyId[n];
            setRefObj[n].gostergeTip = tip[n];
            setRefObj[n].gostergeUrl = url[n];
            setRefObj[n].gostergeUrlTip = urlTipi[n];
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.responseText);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); }
    });
    if (i === detayBodyArray.length - 1) {
        customTimer();
    }
}
```

detayBodyArray coming from another func., refObjArr is a global array

Comment: `refObjArr[0]` should work. We need to see more of your code to help you - specifically, how you create the array and how you pass it to the function

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem inside a working snippet

Comment: This is a combination of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [how Chrome displays arrays in the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: @JJJ that's why i used  
`if (i === detayBodyArray.length - 1) {
                    customTimer();
                }`

Comment: That doesn't make any difference because the Ajax calls haven't finished yet at that point. You'll have to wait until all of them are finished, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Comment: Can you make any plunker or jsfiddle, so that we can investigate the problem?

Comment: i can't reproduce problem, lots of thing going to change on fiddle in example ajax request to my local api , detayBodyArray,veri,bodyId array,url,urltip,tip arrays and n  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with another way. I created simple class like this

```
class refIndicator {

        constructor(ekrandetayId, bodyId, gostergeTip, gostergeUrl, gostergeUrlTip, yS, kS) {
            this.ekrandetayId = ekrandetayId
            this.bodyId = bodyId
            this.gostergeTip = gostergeTip
            this.gostergeUrl = gostergeUrl
            this.gostergeUrlTip = gostergeUrlTip
            this.yS = yS
            this.kS = kS
        }
    }
```

then fill in created and fill reference  in ajax  request then push into global array and it works .

```
     for (var i = 0; i < detayBodyArray.length; i++) {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: apiAdress + '/api/blabla/bla/ekrandetayId=' + detayId[i],
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (veri) {
                         n = detayId.indexOf(veri[2].ekrandetayId);
                         setRefObj = new refIndicator(detayId[veri[2].index], bodyId[n], tip[n], url[n], urlTipi[n], parseInt(veri[2].value), parseInt(veri[2].value));
refObjArr.push(setRefObj)
                         if (refObjArr.length === detayBodyArray.length - 1) {
                             customTimer()
                         }
                     },
                     error: function (msg) {
                         alert(msg.responseText);
                     },
                     beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token); }
                 });

             }



  function customTimer() {
        console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr : ", refObjArr[2])
        console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr kS : ", refObjArr[2].kS)
        console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr edId : ", refObjArr[2].ekrandetayId)
        console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr bId : ", refObjArr[2].bodyId)
        console.log("custom Timer -> refObjArr gTip : ", refObjArr[2].gostergeTip)}
```